# DataTriggers : How it works

Tags: wpf, triggers

I want to implement a `DataTrigger` for say, textBox1.  When `Text` inside textBox1 is "ABC" then I want to display "Data matched!" in another `TextBox` say, textBox2.  I have written below xaml code for this but its not working. I am getting below error message.

```
'Text' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name
```

XAML code for this is:

```
<Window x:Class="ControlTemplateDemo.Animation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Animation" Height="300" Width="607">
<Grid>
    <Border Background="White">
        <StackPanel Margin="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="500" Height="209">
            <TextBox Name="textBox1">                                        
                <TextBox.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <sys:String>ABC</sys:String>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter TargetName="textBox2" Property="Text" Value="Data matched!"/>                            
                    </DataTrigger>
                </TextBox.Triggers>
            </TextBox>                
            <TextBox Name="textBox2">                    
            </TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

Is there any problem in binding?

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `DataTrigger` in a `Style` for the second `TextBox`

something like:

```
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="inputBox" />
  <TextBox Margin="0 25 0 0">
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Text"
                Value="No Match Found" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=inputBox,
                                          Path=Text}"
                        Value="ABC">
            <Setter Property="Text"
                    Value="Match Found" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

[TextBox.Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx) does not support `DataTrigger`. I'd guess it's only for `EventTriggers` as the documentation states

on a side-note, I normally have my bindings in the element that ends up as the target(as much as I can). This way I find it easier to debug at-least personally. If the `TextBox` has wrong info I instantly check it's binding than every binding in my xaml file to see which element has a wrong binding that ends up updating my `TextBox`.